# How to put storage file download excel for laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want to put location storage in my apps, when download file in the folder privacy me. Any idea?

```html
public function getExport(){
  $user = Members::all();
  Excel::create('Export Data',function($excel) use($user){
   $excel->sheet('Sheet 1',function($sheet) use($user){
    $sheet->fromArray($user);
   });
  })->export('xlsx');
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the `->export()` method to `->save('xlsx')`.

If you want to use a custom path, pass that as the 2nd argument like so:

```
->save('xlsx', storage_path('excel/exports'));
```

If you also want to get back the data from the storage, pass `true` as the 3rd argument and alias the closure return to a variable:

```
$file = Excel::create('Export Data',function($excel) use($user){
    $excel->sheet('Sheet 1',function($sheet) use($user){
        $sheet->fromArray($user);
    });
})->save('xlsx', storage_path('excel/exports'), true);
```

Now you can access `$file` to get further information about the storage object.

You can also find more in the [maatwebsite/excel documentation](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export)